# default value for macro declaration

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, compiler-directives

When a macro is created but no value is assigned, is there a default value? `#define MACRO` (end of line).

Macro definition has the syntax: `#define <IDENTIFIER> <value>`. Even if we don't pass a value, the macro is created, which can be verified by the following the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MACRO
int main() {
    #ifdef MACRO
        printf("MACRO was created");
    #endif
    
    return 0;
}
```

Also, if an identifier was not declared using `#define` but passed as the condition for `#ifdef <IDENTIFIER>`, the compiler treats the identifier as though it were the constant zero (false), which can be verified by the following the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    #ifdef A
        printf("No print but valid condition");
    #endif
    
    return 0;
}
```

Which doesn't print anything, but there are no warnings nor errors from the compiler.

My question is, when a macro is created but no value is assigned, is there a default value?

Consider the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MACRO

int main() 
{
    #if defined MACRO
        printf("%d", MACRO);
    #endif
    
    return 0;
}
```

get the error message:

> error: expected expression before ‘)’ token

Which would compile if we assign a value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MACRO 3

int main() 
{
    #ifdef MACRO
        printf("%d", MACRO);
    #endif
    
    return 0;
}
```

My guess is that `#define MACRO` doesn't assign any value, even though `#ifdef` will treat not-defined macros as 0 (or a false condition); Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when a macro is created but no value is assigned, is there a default value?

No, or yes? A macro *defined* without a replacement list like so:

```
#define MACRO
```

expands to nothing, is removed from the processed input. Or the default value is nothing, an empty string, if you want to look at it that way.

> #ifdef , the compiler treats the identifier as though it were the constant zero
>
> #ifdef will treat not-defined macros as 0

No. `#ifdef` only cares about if *defined* or not defined. It doesn't care about the result of the expansion.

`#if` and `#elif` expand the expression and treat *undefined*(!) tokens as 0.

In other words, `#if` and `#elif` *first* expand all the macros, and *then* if there are any tokens that are not numbers or arithmetic operations, then *those* leftover tokens are replaced by 0.

You may want to read [C11 standard 6.10.1p4](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p4) for the source, maybe it will clear things up:

> [...] After all replacements due to macro expansion and the defined unary operator have been performed, all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0, and then each preprocessing token is converted into a token. The resulting tokens compose the controlling constant expression which is evaluated according to the rules ... [...]

> My guess is that #define MACRO doesn't assign any value ... Is that correct?

```
 #define MACRO
 printf("%d", MACRO);
```

expands to `printf("%d", );`. The part `, );` is invalid, thus you get a syntax error.

Comment: `#if FOO`\n`printf("Hello World!");`\n`#endif` will terminate with no errors and no warnings, here the `#if` directive, treats `FOO` as 0 (false), and thus, the condition `printf` will not run. Why is that if `FOO` is an "empty string"?

Comment: I do not understand. If `FOO` is _not_ defined, _then_ `#if FOO` is expanded to `#if 0`. If `FOO` is _defined_ to empty, _then_ `#if FOO` expands to `#if` and that is a compile error. Is FOO defined or not in your code? Consider posting a link to full code in godbolt.com.